# How can i get HDC or ScreenShot from Adobe AIR Application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, air, adobe

first, i appolosize to you my english is very short. but i try my best.

environment:
opengl
win32 api
c++
visual studio 2010

my project is: 
using a application that copy of iPhone maked by Adobe AIR. (it is not my program)
i want texturing that program's screenshot to my opengl. many win32 application can get realtime screenshot with next code:

```
HWND hSrc = ::FindWindow(NULL, "iBBDemo3");
HDC hSrcDC = GetDC(hSrc);
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);

RECT targetRect;
GetClientRect(hSrc,&targetRect);

int width = targetRect.right;
int height = targetRect.bottom;
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

int* t;

BITMAPINFO bmii;
ZeroMemory(&bmii,sizeof(bmii));
bmii.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmii.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmii.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmii.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
bmii.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

HBITMAP hBitMapUsing = CreateDIBSection(hdc,&bmii,DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void**)&t,NULL,0);

HDC dcTarget = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
SelectObject(dcTarget,hBitMapUsing);
RECT rt;
GetClientRect(NULL,&rt);
::PrintWindow(hSrc, dcTarget, 0);

return t; //t is byte array of texture that i want
```

this code works fine. and real-time updated on texture. 
but adobe air application is can't work with this code. 
FindWindow is work fine, getdc is workfine but byte-array of screenshot is black of all-pixel.
who knows why this problem occur or another way to get byte-array of Adobe AIR Application's screenshot? help me!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the [WM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message generated by `PrintWindow` is not being handled by the target. You can try to `BitBlt` directly from the target DC.